# PHP Function: mysql_real_escape_string & set layer to $_POST

Tags: mysql

I want to secure all my inputs to my database. I have written follow function:

```
function mysql_real_escape_array($t){
    return array_map("mysql_real_escape_string",$t);
}
```

In a file which get loaded by all my php datas i have written:

```
$_POST=mysql_real_escape_array($_POST);
```

I think i dont have any disadvantages trough this dirty code and there is no malicious query possible. Or does somebody thinks, that is have any disadvantages trough this code?

Would be happy to hear some feedback. I know it is maybe not the best solution, but in this way i can never forget to escape something.

Thanks!

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO and it will be done for you automatically.

Comment: [Prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) are the way to go.  You can use either the new [MySQLi library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or the [PDO abstraction layer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to surely protect against injection is to use properly parameterized queries.  All parameters to queries have vulnerabilities and must be properly escaped.  This is not just to prevent malicious injection, but to prevent accidental injection.  For example, you could have:

```
SELECT value FROM t1
$value = $result; //$value is now "o'connel"
// SQL error caused by apostrophe in string
SELECT col FROM t2 WHERE value = '$value'
```

You may consider this data safe because it is internal, but it can still cause a problem by not being properly escaped.

About overwriting `$_POST`, note that you can still get the raw post body as well as `$_POST` values from `$_REQUEST`, so there is no way to assure that your data is properly escaped.  What's more is that `mysql_real_escape_string` may not have a valid mysql connection when you need to use it.  This can cause problems and vulnerabilities.  `$_POST` values can also be arrays, so your function would need to be recusive too.

It's *much* easier to forget all those considerations and use parameterized queries with [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli`.  Note that using prepared statements is not enough in and of itself.  You have to properly parameterize the queries.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) either via [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This is the only approach that is really secure and doesn't hurt performance.